For a PLS model fit, how can I calculate R2VX, R2VY, and the cumulative R2VX, R2VY?
According to Eriksson et al. 2013 book "Multi- and Megavariate Data Analysis Basic Principles and Applications", important measures for PLS model performance include $R2VX$ and $R2VY$, which are textually defined as "Explained fraction of the variation of the X/Y variables" and mathematically as:
$$ 
R2VX = 1 - \frac{ \Sigma_i e_{i,k}^2 } { \Sigma_i e_{i,0}^2 }
$$
where $e_{i,k}$ represents the $i$th X-residual of the $k$-component model.
Similarly,
$$ 
R2VY = 1 - \frac{ \Sigma_i f_{i,k}^2 } { \Sigma_i f_{i,0}^2 }
$$
where $f_{i,k}$ represents the $i$th Y-residual of the $k$-component model.
I came up with the following code to calculate $R2VY$:
library(pls)

fit = plsr(hp ~ ., 
     segments = 10,
     scale=T, 
     center=T,
     validation = "CV",
     method = "simpls",
     data=mtcars)

## For component 1
R2VX = 1 - sum(residuals(fit)[,,1]^2)/sum((mtcars$hp - mean(mtcars$hp))^2)
R2VX 

# Matches up with result from R2() function
R2(fit)

However, it is unclear to me how $R2VX$ should be calculated. I am not even sure how to extract the residuals for the X-variables.
Thanks!
